# How can I read the new content writed in an emulated NFC tag in React Native? ( using react-native-nfc-sdk )

Tags: react-native, nfc, hce, react-native-nfc-manager

I am actually using two React Native apps to pass a variable between devices using NFC.

I'm using react-native-nfc-manager to write data over a NFC tag, and react-native-nfc-sdk to emulate the tag on the other device.

Now, i'm able to read and write over the emulated tag, but can't read the new content writed from the nfc-manager app.

I need to be able to read the new content writed over an emulated NFC tag using react-native-nfc-sdk.